# D3js zoom with reset function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, zooming

I'm using D3js for a project and require the zooming function AND the ability to reset the zoom. My problem is that zooming functions act as if resets never happen. Here is the code I have:

```
function load() {
  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%");
  var zoom = d3.zoom().on("zoom", function() {
    d3.select("#vis").attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
  });
  var vis = svg.call(zoom).append("g").attr("id", "vis");
  d3.select("body").on("keypress", function() {
    if (d3.event.shiftKey) {                                                                                                        
      if (d3.event.key == "R") {                                                                                                    
        vis.transition().duration(500).attr("transform", d3.zoomIdentity);
      }
    }
  });
  vis.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100);
}
```

Here is a running example of the problem:
http://bl.ocks.org/nicmcd/a74b0bfba61f50d932dedd6534ad7d9e

How can I get the reset action to reset the internal state of the zooming capability such that future events will base off the reset state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with my code. First, the transition needs to come from `svg` not `vis`. Second, the reset transform can't be done manually using `attr()`, it must be done using `call()`. Here is the revised code that works:

```
  function load() {
    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", "100%")
      .attr("height", "100%");

    var zoom = d3.zoom().on("zoom", function() {
      vis.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    });

    var vis = svg.append("g").attr("id", "vis");
    svg.call(zoom);

    d3.select("body").on("keypress", function() {
      svg.transition().duration(500).attr("transform", d3.zoomIdentity)          
    });

    vis.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 10)
      .attr("y", 10)
      .attr("width", 100)
      .attr("height", 100);
  }
```

Here is a working example:
http://bl.ocks.org/nicmcd/4c730aa64c04bf100a58f224b90c2ff4

Thanks to Andrew Reid for pointing out the errors.

Comment: I spent the entire day debugging this problem in my own code. I found numerous SE answers that didn't work. Yours is the first that did. Thanks!!